# Validating a PIN entered by users

Tags: ruby

How would you refactor this code that checks if users have added a 4+ digit PIN so the code will be as short as possible?

```
def has_pin?
  return self.pin.to_i > 1000 rescue nil
  false
end
```

Ideally without using AR validation on user creation time as they're created with no PIN at first, but may choose to add them later in some specific cases.

PS: the PIN is stored as string for some reason.

Comment: Pin is not a number, it's a string. The rule of thumb is: if you don't need to do math on it, don't store it as a number.

Comment: Use a RegExp match, maybe -- `self.pin =~ /\d{4,}/`? Also, `has_pin?` should have returned `false` for any exception, whereas your code returns `nil`.

Comment: @31piy `pin.size >= 4` :shrug: And handle digit validation when saving the pin.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev -- Agreed! It should be the correct approach.

Comment: very valid comments. some users don't have a PIN set tho, so .size will throw undefined method. Others have some letters in it, I think they pressed their digits for too long on their phone and it entered the letter instead of the digit. This has to be user-proof :)

Comment: @NickM: "so .size will throw undefined method" - trivial to guard against. We give you ideas, it's your job to make it bullet- and user-proof :)

Comment: That's right Sergio! Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with:

```
def pin_valid?
  pin.present? && pin.match?(/\A\d{4,}\z/)
end
```

Why do you aim to have your code as short as possible? I would always aim to have my code as easy to understand as possible.

Comment: "as easy to understand as possible" - to that end, maybe extract the regex into a `has_at_least_n_digits(pin, 4)`, or something. Maybe it's just me, but I always, always trip on regexes.

Comment: Thank you! how about cost? won't matching a regex be a bit more expensive than a .size or a > 1000?

Comment: @NickM: yes, regex is slower. You'll fix this when you measure it to be a bottleneck.

Comment: I have over 1000-2000 concurrents at peak business hours, can't afford the debt. Although my reason for this Q is not performance mainly, but overall code quality.

Comment: @NickM: in any case, don't do the `.to_i > 1000`. It's simply wrong. Here's a valid pin that will be rejected: `0001`

Comment: I think they might have wanted it to be a bit more secure than that

Comment: @NickM: how is `0578` is any "less secure" than `1234`? Don't be one of those apps we all hate (the kind that rejects my password on the grounds of it not having a number, despite it being a 7-word diceware passphrase)

Comment: You're right Sergio, no point annoying them users. So maybe: self.pin.size == 4 && self.pin.to_i > 0?

Comment: `pin.size == 4` doesn't handle 4+ pins. `pin.to_i > 0` would fail for `0000`. You might want to store the regexp in a constant when you want to avoid the performance drawbacks of re-creating the regexp.